# Django. ORM filter by function's keyword argument

Tags: python, django, filter, orm, parameter-passing

I'm trying to extract some records (about magazines) from database to create table with stats. Extraction is made by time period and name of magazin. Here is the code that I currently have, but I suppose it is not DRY enough for two reasons:

```
def get_statistic(date__gte=None, date__lte=None, name=None):
    magazines_qs = Magazines.objects.all()

    #1 move filters to "for"
    #2 get rid of "if" statement (may be by setting default values which 
    #                             makes filter equal to .all() method)
    if date__gte:
        magazines_qs = magazines_qs.filter(date__gte=date__gte)
    if date__lte:
        magazines_qs = magazines_qs.filter(date__lte=date__lte)
    if offer:
        magazines_qs = magazines_qs.filter(name=name)
```

I suppose it is possible to receive something like:

```
def get_statistic(date__gte=None, date__lte=None, name=None):
    magazines_qs = Magazines.objects.all()

    for filter in arguments()
        magazines_qs = magazines_qs.filter(filter)
```

But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a solution that is closer to your original code, so it only accepts a certain set of arguments (it's a combination of the two existing answers):

```
def get_statistic(date__gte=None, date__lte=None, name=None):
    filter_args = {'date__gte': some_date, 'date__lte': some_other_date, 'name': name}
    filter_args = dict((k,v) for k,v in filter_args.iteritems() if v is not None)
    magazines_qs = Magazines.objects.filter(**filter_args)
```

**Note:** This of course only works if you don't have a case where you rely on `None` being passed to the filter method.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, assuming parameters are only ever left out and not explicitly passed as `None`:

```
def get_statistics(**kwargs):
    return Magazines.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

`kwargs` will be a dict containing only the keyword arguments that are explicitly passed in. `.filter(**kwargs)` unpacks these into keyword arguments that are passed to `filter()`.